# DB Connection error when running php artisan:work command on ec2 instance (elastic beanstalk)

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-8

Locally my queues are working perfectly fine. I am using database as the queue_connection but on a beanstalk environment the command php artisan queue:work doesn't run.

**Following are the last few lines of laravel.log file.**

```
 [2022-11-30 12:49:38] development.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'forge', '', Array)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(100): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=127....', 'forge', '', Array)
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(50): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(Object(PDOException), 'mysql:host=127....', 'forge', '', Array)
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127....', Array, Array)
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(184): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#6 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(1064): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#7 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(175): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#8 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(141): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->handleBeginTransactionException(Object(PDOException))
#9 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(115): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->createTransaction()
#10 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(23): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->beginTransaction()
#11 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(223): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->transaction(Object(Closure))
#12 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(345): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->pop('default')
#13 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(354): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}('default')
#14 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(322): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->getNextJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue), 'default')
#15 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runNextJob('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#16 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#17 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#18 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#19 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#20 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#21 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#22 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#23 /var/app/current/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#24 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#25 /var/app/current/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1040): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/app/current/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(301): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/app/current/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /var/app/current/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 {main}
"}
```

As you can see it is trying to connect to localhost while the host in my env is not localhost.

**Following is my config/queue.php file**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Queue Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel's queue API supports an assortment of back-ends via a single
    | API, giving you convenient access to each back-end using the same
    | syntax for every one. Here you may define a default connection.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    | Drivers: "sync", "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", "null"
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'queue_jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

I have even connected my remote DB from my local PC and queues work fine.

I've checked the env on the path /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env and it has the correct contents too.

Comment: It's giving `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`, so it's not liking your database configuration. Try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: The thing is I am not trying to connect to localhost. I am connecting aws db through it's hostname.

Comment: You'll need to find out why it's trying to connect to 127, then. Double-check your settings in your .env file and in your app/config/database.php

Comment: Figured it out. The `queue:work` command wasn't picking env from beanstalk configuration so just had to copy contents of that env to env with in the application folder during build phase.